# Plugin not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, plugin

Created plugin as follows 
**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Model\AdminSessionsManager">
        <plugin name="anshu_custom_admin_logout" type="Anshu\Custom\Model\Plugin\AdminSessionsManager" sortOrder='1' />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Model/Plugin/AdminSessionsManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Model\Plugin;

class AdminSessionsManager extends Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager
{   
    public function beforeprocessLogout()
    {
        exit('--test--');
    }
}
```

But it is not working. 
What can be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Did you try beforeProcessLogout(). And also try to use exit() after echo.

Comment: Yes, I tried beforeProcessLogout() as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In magento 2.2: **Magento\Backend\Model\AdminSessionsManager** class does not exist.

Change your config following way:

```
<type name="Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager">
    <plugin name="anshu_custom_admin_logout" 
            type="Anshu\Custom\Plugin\Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager" 
            sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And class

```
namespace Anshu\Custom\Plugin\Magento\Security\Model;

class AdminSessionsManager
{
    public function beforeProcessLogout(
        \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $subject
    ) {
        error_log('beforeProcessLogout');
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

Please try Following code for your plugin

in your **app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Model\AdminSessionsManager">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Anshu_Custom_Plugin_Magento_Backend_Model_AdminSessionsManager" sortOrder="0" type="Anshu\Custom\Plugin\Magento\Backend\Model\AdminSessionsManager"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and add following in your **app/code/Anshu/Custom/Plugin/Magento/Backend/Model/AdminSessionsManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Plugin\Magento\Backend\Model;

class AdminSessionsManager
{

    public function beforeProcessLogout(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\AdminSessionsManager $subject,
        //$functionvariables
    ) {
        //Your plugin code
    }
}
```